# Calculate deltavalue difference by timestamp and device

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have two tables in my database. One for my devices, one for the recorded values.

I need to retrieve the the Delta Value between every time-stamp and only from the same device of course.

The Devices table I only use to choose filter on a device. And in the Recorded values table I am only retrieving the values and time-stamp:

One query I made to show this data goes the following:

```
SELECT    TOP(100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp DESC) AS  ROW#, dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp, dbo.Channels.Description, dbo.RecordedValues.Value, dbo.Channels.Tag
FROM dbo.Channels INNER JOIN dbo.RecordedValues ON dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.SourceId AND dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.ChannelId
WHERE     (dbo.Channels.Description LIKE N'%AL Electra%')
```

Example of table:

```
Row|Timestamp              |Description            |Value   |Tag
1  |2017-09-13 10:55:00.077| 51 Electra Consumption|503.3953|AB12
1  |2017-09-13 10:45:00.077| 51 Electra Consumption|493.3953|AB12
```

Let's say these are the values I get when I execute the query. Now I want to know the delta value. So I tried this piece of code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp DESC) AS Rows, dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp, dbo.Channels.Description, dbo.RecordedValues.Value, dbo.RecordedValues.Deltavalue, dbo.Channels.Tag, LEAD(dbo.RecordedValues.Value) OVER (ORDER BY dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp) dbo.RecordedValues.Value
FROM dbo.Channels INNER JOIN dbo.RecordedValues ON dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.SourceId AND dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.ChannelId
WHERE(dbo.Channels.Description LIKE N'%AL Electra%')
```

Then I get get an error Nvarchar cannot substract. So I found that you have to change to INT. Since I don't have rights to change properties in the database, I thought that I could cast it.

So I tried this piece of code, which I put in the select clause:

```
(cast(dbo.RecordedValues.Value AS int)),
```

If I execute it I still can't substract it, so I tried it with out the piece of code which allows me to calculate delta value and then it gives me it can't convert to INT.

So I don't know what to do now anymore. So if someone knows the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which value can not convert to `int`, `RecordedValues.Value`? Try casting to decimal. `cast(dbo.RecordedValues.Value AS decimal(10,5))`

Comment: Yes recordedvalues.value!  Thanks with decimal I can convert it. But now how can I get the delta value from this column? When I try to use code LEAD OVER and point to the new column with the decimal values. It says the column name is wrong? Why is this. Is this because the column is shown temporary and not in the database table? Or is my piece of code to create the delta values incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, simplify your query so it is readable:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rv.Timestamp DESC) AS Rows, 
       rv.Timestamp, c.Description, rv.Value, rv.Deltavalue, c.Tag,
       (LEAD(rv.Value) OVER (ORDER BY rv.Timestamp) - rv.Value) as diff
FROM dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
     dbo.RecordedValues rv
     ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.SourceId = rv.ChannelId
WHERE c.Description LIKE N'%AL Electra%';
```

Table aliases make the query easier to read.  The `TOP (100)` is unnecessary.

For this to work, you need to convert to a numeric format.  In fact, you should fix the table!

```
alter table dbo.RecordedValues alter column Value numeric(20, 4);
```

Perhaps -- for some reason -- you cannot do that.  If that is the case, use `try_convert()`.  Here is a simple way using a subquery:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rv.Timestamp DESC) AS Rows, 
       rv.Timestamp, c.Description, rv.Value, rv.Deltavalue, c.Tag,
       (LEAD(rv.Value_num) OVER (ORDER BY rv.Timestamp) - rv.Value_num) as diff
FROM dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.value) as value_num
      FROM dbo.RecordedValues rv
     ) rv
     ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.SourceId = rv.ChannelId
WHERE c.Description LIKE N'%AL Electra%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think it will work but sadly I can't test it out, because whenever I try to execute I get a timeout. I had this problem before when I tried to execute a query which orders by valueA and valueB. So I need to figure out first why that is happening.

Comment: @IonK. . . . This should have essentially the same performance plan as the query you use with a `lead()`.

Comment: I figured out why it timed out sometimes. I had it timestamp on ASC. And because the database is way to big it times out, I think... Do you think that is plausible?

Comment: @IonK. . .  That is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
SELECT TOP (100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp DESC) AS Rows, 
    dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp, 
    dbo.Channels.Description, 
    dbo.Channels.Tag, 
    CAST(LEAD(dbo.RecordedValues.Value) OVER (ORDER BY dbo.RecordedValues.Timestamp) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) - 
    CAST(dbo.RecordedValues.Value AS DECIMAL(10,5))
FROM dbo.Channels 
INNER JOIN dbo.RecordedValues ON dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.SourceId AND dbo.Channels.SourceId = dbo.RecordedValues.ChannelId
WHERE(dbo.Channels.Description LIKE N'%AL Electra%');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think it will work but sadly I can't test it out, because whenever I try to execute I get a timeout. I had this problem before when I tried to execute a query which orders by valueA and valueB. So I need to figure out first why that is happening.